# Find and check out a file to particular changelist in Perforce

Tags: perforce

I want to search for various files in the the depot and check them out in a changelist. There is large number of files so I want to do it using commands.

I have tried the command
`p4 -c client_name where abc.java` but it is not able to search inside the directory.

Answer (score 1):

First set your client name so that you don't have to keep typing it into each command...

```
p4 set P4CLIENT=client_name
```

Are you trying to open all of the files named `abc.java` regardless of which directory they're in?

```
p4 edit //.../abc.java
```

Or just under the current directory?

```
p4 edit .../abc.java
```

Or all `.java` files?

```
p4 edit //....java
```

Or all files that were submitted by user `bob` during the month of April 2018?

```
p4 -F @=%change% -Ztag changes -u bob @2018/04/01,@2018/04/30 | p4 -F %depotFile% -x - files | p4 -x - edit
```

To make these files go into a particular pending changelist that you've already created on this client, add `-c CHANGE` to the `p4 edit` command.

Comment: I want to find if there are multiple files with same name `abc.java` present at different locations using `p4 where` command. If there are multiple files then there is no need to check out the files to changelist

Comment: `p4 files //.../abc.java` will do it.  You actually can't do this at all via the `p4 where` command -- that tells you *where* a path is mapped but not what *files* are there.  :)